# How to Sync and Consolidate Data from Multiple local database to live server database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, api

My plan is to store data in my local MySQL database and after a time interval it will update my live MySQL database remotely. Is it possible?

I'm planning a inventory management script in PHP MySQL. I will install web application locally to my clients and it will backup local data to live server via **API** or any **library**.

**Can any one suggest me any library for this all.**

**Thanks is advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with different methods:

- Database Replication (recommended solution), it almost handles everything perfectly. You can read different tutorials available on internet to use it.
- Scheduled PHP script to sync data on your specified occasions. There are several packages available for this, i.e. https://github.com/mrjgreen/db-sync. For scheduling  you can use CronTab or supervisor or etc.

But I would personally recommend you to use replication, since it is a native DBMS solution for such scenarios.

Comment: actually I created a exe setup using **php desktop**  it will install in multiple users. there is no fixed users. just we will send him setup. so tell me please any proper solution for this.

Comment: @HedayatH On initial setup you can have write an API, which will tell you that a new setup has happened, so you can create your database in your remote server and configure it, then return it to the installation. Then there you can continue with the above solutions.